# Add the_post_thumbnail_url to a shortcode in function.php

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode

I want to display a popup by CodeLights on every WC product. For this I put this in my child theme's function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'childReview' );
function childReview() {
  echo do_shortcode('[cl-popup size="l" title="Click!" btn_label="Headline" btn_bgcolor="#006982" btn_color="#ffffff" overlay_bgcolor="rgba(0,105,130,0.75)" title_textcolor="#006982" content_textcolor="#006982"]Some Content goes here
[/cl-popup]');
}
```

This works absolutely fine.
Now I want to add the product's image to each popup.
What I tried is to put this into the content part of the shortcode, so behind "Some content goes here":

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" width="300" height="300" />
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work at all. The popup works but the images src just remains as `<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>`, so the image doesn't appear.

Does anyone have some advice for me?

Thanks a lot and BR,
Dario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just printing your function as a string, try concatonating:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'childReview' );
function childReview() {

  global $post;

  echo do_shortcode('[cl-popup size="l" title="Click!" btn_label="Headline" btn_bgcolor="#006982" btn_color="#ffffff" overlay_bgcolor="rgba(0,105,130,0.75)" title_textcolor="#006982" content_textcolor="#006982"]<img src=" ' . wp_get_attachment_url ( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ) . '"/>
[/cl-popup]');
}
```

Comment: Hi @MrBizle, thanks for your answer. I got a step further with it: the URL of the thumbnail is now being displayed. But not in the popup but before the generated button. And it's a URL that is being diplayed, not the image...

Comment: Cool! Are you sure you can put HTML in that shortcode? Sounds like might be stripping it out. Have you got a link bud?

Comment: Hi @MrBizle, hum, I'm sure that I can use HTML in that shortcode. Images, Headlines,... no problem. Not sure about PHP though...You can find the blue button with popup here: http://www.wohngeschwister.de/produkt/bowl-nor-blau/. The generated URL appears above the button. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: It doesn't appear to be rendering the src URL at all 

Comment: `<div class="cl-popup-box-content" style="color:#006982;background-color:#ffffff;"><img src="">
 <h2>Drei Wege zum Produkt</h2>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.wohngeschwister.de/kontakt/">Besuch uns am Grossneumarkt!</a></li>
  <li>Schreib uns eine E-Mail: <a href="http://www.wohngeschwister.de/kontakt/">info@wohngeschwister.de</a></li>
  <li>oder ruf uns an: <a href="tel:04046643937">040/466 439 37</a></li>
</ul>`

Comment: Yes, that's what I also recognized. Do you know why it behaves like this? If I add the shortcode within the backend editor, the shortcode plugin adds this class to the image: 'class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-5321"'. Maybe it has something to do with this?

Comment: Okay lets go at this another way, Can inside the childReview function, can you var_dump(the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID)) and tell me the output

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail_url` doesn't take a post ID as the parameter. Try `wp_get_attachment_url ( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) )` instead.

Comment:  You're right, although i think it will just ignore that bit and use the global $post;

Comment: Awesome!!! It worked, thanks a lot to both of you!!

Comment: @MrBizle I added another topic related to this one, maybe you have another helpful piece of advice there? ;-) http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235518/add-echo-div-with-analytics-code-to-function-in-functions-php