# Add/echo div with Analytics-Code to function in functions.php

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I want to do something special I think. I need to add a html-snippet with GA-Code to a function in functions.php.
To do this I thought to add this piece of code:

```
echo ('<div onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'will-ich-haben', 'klick', 'test-klick');">');
```

to this function:

```
// Will ich haben
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'childReview' );
function childReview() {

  global $post;

  echo do_shortcode('[cl-popup size="l" btn_label="Will ich haben!" btn_bgcolor="#006982" btn_color="#ffffff" overlay_bgcolor="rgba(0,105,130,0.75)" title_textcolor="#006982" content_textcolor="#006982"]
<p align="center" style="color: #999999;"><i>' .get_the_title( $post_id ). '</i></p>
 <img style="width: 400px; height: auto; float: left;" src="' .wp_get_attachment_url ( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ). '"/>
 <h2>So kommst du zum Produkt:</h2>
 <ul style="margin-left: 50px;">
    <li><a href="http://www.wohngeschwister.de/kontakt/">Besuch uns am Grossneumarkt!</a></li>
    <li>Schreib uns eine E-Mail: <a href="mailto:info@wohngeschwister.de?subject=Interesse%20an%20' .get_the_title( $post_id ). '">info@wohngeschwister.de</a></li>
    <li>oder ruf uns an: <a href="tel:04046643937">040/466 439 37</a></li>
</ul>
&Uuml;brigens: Egal f&uuml;r welchen Weg du dich entscheidest, in Zusammenarbeit mit <a href="http://delivva.de/" target="_blank">delivaa </a>liefern wir dir dein Lieblingsprodukt innerhalb von 60 Minuten innerhalb Hamburgs!
[/cl-popup]');
}
```

I tried to simply add it but that occured an error. Do you know how to integrate it a smart way? Goal: Measure clicks on the button which is generated through the shortcode.

Huge thanks in advance,
Dario

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ('<div onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'will-ich-haben', 'klick', 'test-klick');">');
```

I haven't looked any further but as a first step, this string isn't concatenated correctly.

```
echo "<div onClick='ga('send', 'event', 'will-ich-haben', 'klick', 'test-klick')'></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks, that brought me a step further again. I started with these stuff to be honest ;-) So, I come to another modification: I tried to add ' .get_the_title( $post_id ). ' to the code, so that it is `echo "<div onClick='ga('send', 'event', 'will-ich-haben', 'klick', ' .get_the_title( $post_id ). ')'>";` but that doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure, probably, I have to put some () or {} or "" before and behind .get_the_title( $post_id ). but I can't find out which one to be correct...

Comment: OK, I got it myself. I just added a variable $label and defined it by   `$galabel = get_the_title($post_id);`. Thanks a lot that you brought me to this way :)